# What is the main intention of creating a subtype with NewType?

Tags: python, types

I thought I could pass a value of a subtype where a value of a base type is expected.  What I mean by saying that is as follows.

```py
from typing import NewType


BaseType = NewType("BaseType", int)
SubType1 = NewType("SubType1", BaseType)
SubType2 = NewType("SubType2", BaseType)

def return_age(age: BaseType) -> BaseType:
    return age

return_age(SubType1(666))  # 1

return_age(SubType2(666))  # 2
```

And mypy says

```
# 1: error: Argument 1 to "SubType1" has incompatible type "int"; expected "BaseType"  [arg-type]
# 2: error: Argument 1 to "SubType2" has incompatible type "int"; expected "BaseType"  [arg-type]
```

I expected to be able to use a basetype and a subtype as a baseclass and a subclass.

```py
class BaseClass: pass


class SubClass1(BaseClass): pass


class SubClass2(BaseClass): pass



def return_class(klass: BaseClass) -> BaseClass:
    return klass


return_class(SubClass1())

return_class(SubClass2())
```

That example above is completely valid usage whereas the subtype example is not. I am just trying to understand the main distinction of being a subclass and a subtype in that matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've misdiagnosed the problem. Look at the error messages again:

```
# 1: error: Argument 1 to "SubType1" has incompatible type "int"; expected "BaseType"  [arg-type]
# 2: error: Argument 1 to "SubType2" has incompatible type "int"; expected "BaseType"  [arg-type]
```

mypy has absolutely no problems with you passing a SubType1 or SubType2 where a BaseType is expected. It's spitting out error messages because you're passing an int **to `SubType1` and `SubType2`**.

You need to call those like `SubType1(BaseType(666))` and `SubType2(BaseType(666))`.